# wysiwyg.js editor enabled only for first <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

I'm trying to add http://wysiwygjs.github.io/ editor to my CMS.

It seems the demo enables editors via this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Featured editor
    $('#editor1,#editor2,#editor3').each( function(index, element)
    {
```

so I've removed #editor2 and #editor3 to just keep editor1 which I need.

Then enabled it in my script via:

```
<textarea name="tresc[%id]" id="editor1">
```

and it worked only for the first textarea, the rest did not have the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the cited page, you will see that the toolbar is contained within a  separate div `<div class="wysiwyg-toolbar wysiwyg-toolbar-top">...</div>` above the textarea field. Ensure you have the wysiwyg js files correctly installed and you should be able to implement this.

Also note that if you are trying to implement for more than one textarea, do not re-use the same id, use a class or increment the id.